# Escape @ Character in Javadoc

Tags: java, java-8, javadoc

I know that this has been asked before but the answers there only worked with older JVMs; I'm on 8.  I have a javadoc like this:

```
 * <pre>
 * {@code
 * 
 * import javax.ws.rs.Path;
 * 
 * import com.ziath.handheldserver.scripts.AbstractHandheldScript;
 * import com.ziath.handheldserver.scripts.valueobjects.ScriptStatus;
 * import com.ziath.handheldserver.scripts.valueobjects.WidgetList;
 * 
 * import org.slf4j.Logger;
 * import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
 * 
 * @Path("myBasicScript")
```

I need to escape the '@' symbol; I've tried the following:

- Replace the @ with the html representation so @Override becomes @Override.  This just prints @Override in the jdocs
- Replace the @Override with {@literal @}Override.  This now prints {@literal @}Override in the javadocs.
- Replace the @Override with @literal @Override; this doesn't escape the @ symbol and the javadocs stop parsing.

  Does anyone know how to do this with JDK 8?  I'm surprised at how difficult it is!

Comment: Are you using an IDE to view the Javadoc?

Comment: No a web browser; Chrome

Comment: I don't know if it matters but this is in the package-info.java section of the javadocs

Comment: What about removing the `{@code ...}` tag and just going with the HTML `<pre>...</pre>` element alone?

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you're asking. If you only want to escape the `@` character, then you can use the character entity `&#64;`

Comment: As you can see in my original question - I tried that and it just printed &#64; in the javadocs

Comment: @KevinAnderson that works but it makes the docs look ugly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked for an example of code with an @ sign in the JDK. The `@SafeVarargs` annotation has that. Its [source code](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/SafeVarargs.java/?v=source) does not use a `<code>` block but a `<blockquote><pre>` instead.

```
/**
 * <blockquote><pre>
 * import javax.ws.rs.Path;
 * 
 * import com.ziath.handheldserver.scripts.AbstractHandheldScript;
 * import com.ziath.handheldserver.scripts.valueobjects.ScriptStatus;
 * import com.ziath.handheldserver.scripts.valueobjects.WidgetList;
 * 
 * import org.slf4j.Logger;
 * import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
 * 
 * &#064;Path("myBasicScript")
 * </pre></blockquote>
 */
```

This works for me on Java 8 and it looks reasonably good. I'd agree it's a bit odd to not use `@code`, however.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{@literal @}` to accomplish this for a single occurrence of an `@` character in text. Alterantively, if you want to include a code block in your JavaDoc and want *all* `@` characters to be escaped, I recommend to use `<pre>` blocks in combination with `{@code}` like so:

```
* <pre>
* {@code
* ... my code here...
* }
* </pre>
```

Comment: I did that; if you look at the question I have that in my javadocs and if I don't escape it then it stops parsing and if I use {@literal @} it prints {@literal @} in the javadocs.

Comment: That's weird. I've been using it this way for ages... Maybe you ran into a bug of some sort? Did you check that you properly open and close the `<pre>` tag? Try checking your `javadoc` logs for compile errors, maybe something else is going wrong as well which causes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `{@literal @}`. This is the example for `@`, but you can use `{@literal}` for any special characters

Comment: I did that; see in the question.  It prints {@literal @} in the javadocs.  I assume that this is because it is in the {@code tag.  See below for the example:

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
 
 {@literal @}Path("myBasicScript")
 public class MyBasicScript extends AbstractHandheldScript{
 
  private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyBasicScript.class);